# Using shared_ptr with an abject that is typedef from void*

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I am running into some problems porting some code that uses smart pointers.

Old code..

```
shared_ptr<Foo> create_Foo();
```

Where Foo is internally created via a function

```
Foo* Foo::FooFactory;
```

So i understand that we are creating a Ptr to a C++ class/object and then passing that ptr to the shared Ptr object to create a shared ptr that holds a ptr to an object of the type Foo...

But what happens when i want to create a smart ptr to hold an object that is typdef'd as an object form a void*?

Eg.

```
typdef void* FOO_HANDLE
shared_ptr<FOO_HANDLE> create_foo();
```

With an internal factory func like

```
FOO_HANDLE FooFactory();
```

Basically i am confused about to declare and create the shared_ptr object with a the typedef FOO_HANDLE object, that is essentially a void*!
Also because the FOO_HANDLE is a ptr to a C object it gets destroyed via a destroy method ala,

```
FooDestory(FOO_HANDLE);
```

So i guess i also need to tell the smart_prt about the method to destory the object.

I am starting to think that using smart ptrs here is the wrong approach..
but thought i would ask here first...

- james

Comment: Smart pointers are typed, period.

Comment: You can provide smart pointers with custom deleters. Also, prefer `unique_ptr` over `shared_ptr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::shared_ptr<void>` can hold a `void*`. When you construct such a `shared_ptr`, you need to provide the deleter, which will be type-erased (and is hence not part of the `shared_ptr` type itself). You can do this:

```
shared_ptr<void> create_foo() {
    return {FooFactory(), FooDestroy};
}
```

Comment: ...except it should be `shared_ptr<void>` or `shared_ptr<*FOO_HANDLE>`. Which is kinda ugly but would do the job.